# Which one is correct-"life" or "lives"?

Tags: word-usage

I am not sure about what is correct use of words in the following line:

- They lost their **lives** saving our lives.

or

- They lost their **life** saving our lives.

Comment: Got any theories?  Research?  Anything?

Comment: sorry i cud not understand your question. Are you asking about if i have been working on publishing research papers?

Comment: @msj003 He is asking for proof that you have tried to answer this question for yourself before turning to Stack Exchange.

Comment: ohhhh i am sorry for misinterpretation. No i don't have any proof as such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Singular noun objects of plural subjects](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114077/singular-noun-objects-of-plural-subjects)

Comment: Was this just anyone who lost their life, or some specific set of people who lost their lives?

Comment: @tchrist. This was for a specific set of people.

Answer (score 3):

A plural subject requires a plural object (*lives*), accordingly a singular subject requires a singular object (*life*).

*They* can be used to mean one person or several people, however.

So, if your intention is to refer to an individual who lost his or her life whilst saving the lives of more than one others, then the second is correct and the first incorrect. *They* is singular in this context, so you should use the singular, *life*.

However, if you mean that more than one person lost their lives whilst saving the lives of more than one others, then the first is correct, the second incorrect.

---

If the latter is what you are trying to say, a good suggestion made in the comments of this answer is that you leave off the second *lives*. It's not required because if you write *ours* then you convey that several of their lives were lost in saving several of our lives.

> They lost their lives saving ours.

Comment: Unless "they" were all helping play a single player in a role-playing game.

Comment: It could also be shortened to: "They lost their lives saving ours" to avoid repeating the plural noun.

Comment: Someone might bring up the singular "they" pronoun. When the identity of the rescuer is unknown instead  of saying "He or she lost his or her life saving our lives", the singular "they" is often used. [Oh, actually I have brought it up!]

Comment: @Mari-LouA -d'oh, of course! How could I not notice that. I had assumed completely that the OP had meant several life savers, though of course it could well be just one. I've edited my answer now. I think that should cover all eventualities.

Comment: i am new here.But this site is just amazing full of amazing people.