# Members must use their own cards ,or, members must use their own card?

Tags: grammatical-number

Which is correct? Members must use their own cards, or, members must use their own card?

Comment: Plural gives the impression that members have multiple cards.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The question that you marked this one as a duplicate of is not a duplicate. In that question, the construct "Remind your wives / wife" is different. There, the sentence is an imperative—which means that the subject is always **you**—but it is left ambiguous if it is a plural or singular "you."

Comment: Related:[https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262825/which-one-is-correct-life-or-lives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262825/which-one-is-correct-life-or-lives) and [Our bodies' or our body's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12750/our-bodies-or-our-bodys)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I second your own duplication suggestion.

Comment: @Jason Bassford "It is not wrong (where no real scope for misinterpretation would ensue) to address the (common) individual within a group: '[Students,] hold the protractor down with one hand.' " is my answer there to the title question, "Do you pluralize the singular possessions of individual members of a plural group?" OP only offers an example to illustrate; the title question is more general. // 'All children  must be accompanied by a parent or guardian' is totally acceptable, and pragmatics bars the ludicrous reading.

Answer (score 0):

The correct version is:

> **Members** must use their own **cards**.

You are talking about a collective group of people, which, here, is also plural. So, the noun (as the members don't share ownership of a single card) is plural too.

In order for the singular *card* to be correct, you would need to change the sentence to use a singular subject:

> **Each member** must use their own **card**.

Note: I am using *their* in the singular third-person. For clarity, of if you don't agree with this use, it can be rephrased:

> **Each member** must use her or his own **card**.

Or, with additional rephrasing:

> As **a member**, you must use your own **card**.

Note that the use of **own** increases the awkwardness of any construction here. If you remove **own**, the grammatically correct subject-verb version sounds better:

> Members must use their cards.

However, if the point is to say "don't use another member's card," then using the singular "member" with **own** (and *card*) is the better (grammatically correct) solution.

---

Apparently, I have to provide more evidence for my assertion.

Here is what [Public Works and Government Services Canada](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_v&page=95TrTtTB_flE.html) (the leading source for grammar in the Canadian government) currently says

```
When to use a plural verb

When the members of a collective noun are performing an action as
individuals, use a plural verb. In this case, all or some members of
the group are doing something independently of the other members; the
group is not acting together as a unit.

The orchestra are tuning their instruments.
The cast have been practising their lines.
The flock were running off in every direction.
The staff disagree on the proposal.

In many cases, it may sound more natural to make the subject plural in
form by adding a word like members:

The members of the orchestra are tuning their instruments.
The cast members have been practising their lines.
The staff members disagree on the proposal.
```

Note that wherever individual ownership of an individual item is used, the item still takes the plural form—because the subject takes the plural form.

In a [blog post](http://www.dummies.com/education/language-arts/grammar/how-to-select-pronouns-for-collective-nouns/) by Geraldine Woods, the author of *English Grammar for Dummies*:

> Collective nouns (*committee*, *team*, *squad*, *army*, *class*, and the like)
>   refer to groups. How do you choose a pronoun to refer to that
>   committee, squad, or team? When the group is acting as a unit—doing
>   the same thing at the same time—the noun is singular and the
>   pronouns that refer to it are also singular. In this situation, the
>   collective noun is paired with a singular verb also (if the collective
>   noun is a subject).
>
> Right about now you’re probably wondering what happens when the group
>   isn’t acting as one unit. Simple. Just break the group down into its
>   component parts and go for plural verbs and pronouns, as in this
>   sentence:

```
Some members of the squad are eating pizza while others are oiling their rocket launchers.
```

> Now you have a plural subject (members) partnering a plural verb (are)
>   and a plural pronoun (their).

And, I will add, a plural object (launchers).

If the question is "What is grammatically correct?" then the answer is what I have already given. If you don't *like* the grammatically correct answer, or you feel that it communicates some kind of confusion, then ignore it—but do so with the knowledge that you are doing something technically ungrammatical.

Comment: -1 Rephrasing is not an answer. The question ("Which is correct?") is about the grammatical correctness and semantic adequacy of the alternatives.

Comment: @kris The very first sentence in my answer gave the correct version—and then explained why it was the grammatically correct version. The rest of the answer was simply additional information.

Comment: Please see also my comment at OP.

Comment: @kris Yes. It's perfectly possible for something to be grammatically correct yet also have awkward phrasing or a misleading meaning. Which is why I provided the technically correct answer—and, additionally, some rephrased answers that are both correct *and* unambiguous.

Comment: There's nothing awkward in using the singular in this sentence AFAI can see.

Comment: The question ' Do you [need to] pluralize the singular possessions of individual members of a plural group?' has already been addressed, and supporting evidence (Dorgeloh and Wanner, in 'Syntactic Variation and Genre') for the acceptability of using a singular form given.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have updated my answer with two *modern* grammar sources in support of my contention.

Comment: @kris As a grammarian and editor, I find the ungrammatical singular (in the original construction) to be awkward. It is not one I would ever use. Everything being equal, a rephrasing can easily be grammatical without any awkwardness (for anyone).

Comment: I very nearly upvoted but it's not so clear cut as you make it out to be. See this old question of mine on ELL [They write in their school diary (or) diaries?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110914/they-write-in-their-school-diary-or-diaries)

Comment: Also consider this post on EL&U [Singular noun objects of plural subjects](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114077/singular-noun-objects-of-plural-subjects) I think Trevor D's answer strikes a good balance between grammaticality and idiomatic usage

Comment: Your sources are answering a different question. This is not about a plural or singular ***verb***, but a plural or singular ***object***. The rules are different, at least in American English. So all you really have from the sources are three examples, which is way too small a sample to derive grammatical rules from.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The fact that we use a living language makes "correctness" a moving target. There will always be a good reason to go against "the rules" in some instances. It's difficult when prescriptivism and descriptivism clash—or to know the context behind some questions (like the one originally asked here).

Comment: They're ***both*** correct, and in this case it doesn't matter. Sometimes it does. For example, there is a big difference between *"all members may bring a guest"* and *"all members may bring guests,"* and you should use the first if you don't want to risk being inundated by zillions of guests.

Comment: Those address notional verb-subject agreement, not subject-complement agreement.