# Apostrophe in "Play is our brains favorite way of learning."?

Tags: apostrophe

Should there be an apostrophe in the following sentence. If so, where?

"Play is our brains favorite way of learning."

Comment: I would suggest that it is actually more colloquial to say _play is the brain's favourite way of learning_  which, incidentally, avoids the problem which I think you are trying to highlight.

Comment: Similar: [Members must use their own cards ,or, members must use their own card?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443154)

Comment: @NigelJ You still need an apostrophe. What really are you implying?

Comment: Voted for migration to [ell.se]

Comment: The sentence will remain ambiguous and confusing without rephrasing of some kind. Either what @NigelJ suggested—which seems best to me, or something like *Play is each of our brain's favourite way of learning.* (That's less ambiguous, but also more awkward.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Our bodies' or our body's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12750/our-bodies-or-our-bodys)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it depends:

*****"Play is our brains favorite way of learning." -- ungrammatical; doesn't make sense.

"Play is our **brain's** favorite way of learning." -- the brain of each of us.

"Play is our **brains'** favorite way of learning." -- the brains of ours.

HTH.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but two and three both seem wrong. I don't share a brain with anyone else, in two. Three, to me, doesn't need an apostrophe since it says 'our'.

Comment: Huh, @NigelJ We are discussing English here.

Comment: Yes indeed. I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need an apostrophe.

To me, “our brain’s” doesn't make any sense because I can only interpret “our brain” as meaning “the single brain belonging to us collectively”. So I would only use “our brains’ ”. But different English speakers apparently have different intuitions about the acceptability of expressions like these.

As I mentioned in the comments, a related question is [Members must use their own cards ,or, members must use their own card?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443154/members-must-use-their-own-cards-or-members-must-use-their-own-card) I didn't look through the linked questions earlier, but now I have, and I have found one that I think is a duplicate: [Our bodies' or our body's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12750/our-bodies-or-our-bodys).

Answer (score -3):

"Play is our brain's favorite way of learning."

In this sentence'Play' is a noun, 'is' is a verb and 'our brain's favorite way of learning' is a complement. Therefore there should not be an apostrophe.

Comment: Huh? "Therefore there should **not** be an apostrophe."?

Comment: But you used an apostrophe . . .