# Cashews are excellent sources of magnesium?

Tags: grammatical-number, agreement

A mistake I've heard many English learners use happens to be really hard to explain, so I'll give some examples:

- *Scissors are major causes of blindness among irresponsible children* instead of "Scissors are a major cause of blindness among irresponsible children" (hopefully false)
- *Cashews are excellent sources of magnesium* instead of "cashews are an excellent source of magnesium"

The pattern seems to be cases when all things of a certain category are described as a certain way, where the things happen to be plural. As a native speaker, I know that treating the subject as singular sounds far more correct than treating the subject as plural. The sense is that we're not describing individual items from a category, which would be plural, but rather the one category itself which is singular.

Is there a name for this type of grammatical construction and is there a general rule indicating in which situations it applies?

Comment: There is a fake rule that subjects and subject complements must match in number. See [Subject/Complement Agreement...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187084/subject-complement-agreement-how-to-describe-problem-with-the-thing-is-the-obj), especially the comment by @tchrist (for a concise overview): _"The only agreement rule is that finite verbs must agree with their subject. Period. There is no such thing as “subject–complement” agreement in English, be it grammatical or notional._ The problem is the horses _is perfectly normal, standard, and correct in all possible ways..."_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singular noun objects of plural subjects](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114077/singular-noun-objects-of-plural-subjects)

Comment: The problem is that scissors do not form many causes, and cashews do not form many sources of magnesium.